# Measuring quality in the Front End Development space?

Tags: html, css, frontend

How do you go about measuring quality in the Front End Development space?

Are there any tools/techniques/best practices you feel are particluarly relevant? e.g. Unit Testing for JavaScript, YSlow, page validation?

Would be interetsed to know others thoughts on this as i think it is open ended.  For example you could say that a mark of quality is that the finished site looks the same in all browsers, html passes validation as does CSS.

Those points are contestable as i personally don't believe that validation is that important and/or a finished site should necessarily look the same in all browsers e.g absence of rounded corners in those browsers that do not support them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To manually Check the front end development:**

Look at the website:

- Does it look good?
- Does it feel polished?
- Does it work without JavaScript
- Is JavaScript only used to enhance the website (Ignoring JavaScript only web applications)
- Does the basic functionality work in Chrome, FF 3.6, FF4, IE8, IE9, Opera10, Opera11, Safari4, Safari5.
- Does the JavaScript interfer with the experience.
- Is there a too heavy reliance on Flash/Java/Unity/SilverLight ?
- Is the JavaScript minified/gzipped?

Look at the un-minified code:

- is the HTML semantically correct?
- Does the HTML make any sense to screen readers or the blind audience
- are the correct HTML entities used. (No tables for layout)
- does the CSS enhance the HTML
- Is there a seperation of HTML and CSS.
- Does it confirm to 4.01, XHTML1.1 or HTML5 validation?
- Does the CSS have meaning full names.
- Is the JavaScript modularly written?
- Does the JavaScript adhere to ES3 standards?
- Make sure there is minimal browser sniffing.

And the list goes on and on.

The important thing is good HTML with CSS used to enhance the UI and layout and that the JavaScript enhances the functionality correctly.

Also ensure that 3rd party applications like flash and SilverLight are only used for complex applications or powerful animations.

Oh and of course check It's not auto generated nonsense from ASP.NET, WordPress, SharePoint, etc.

> Are there any tools/techniques/best
>   practices you feel are particluarly
>   relevant? e.g. Unit Testing for
>   JavaScript, YSlow, page validation?

Reading your question more carefully I've handled it at a tangent. If you want automated tools the HTML validation is good. Using external tools like YSlow is great. Using js unit testing is great. These are all good and valid tools you should use.

I'm sure there are more but I don't have personal experience to recommend any.

Comment: Thanks Raynos.  I know it is a subjective question but was keen to know others thoughts.  Working in a .Net environment these guys have many techniques that they want to extend to include the front end code but do not necessarily apply as HTML and CSS is not really code in the same sense as .Net.

Comment: I appreciate you handling it at teh tagent you did.  That's more of what i wanted as i am well aware of the specific tools to measure quality.

Comment: @RyanP13 feel free to visit [JavaScript SO Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) to discuss the importance of particular things specifically. Realise that my list is of things you would do in an "ideal world". We ignore deadlines and practicality. I'm all for cutting corners when there's enough to gain.

Comment: @Raynos - To be fair, the first couple of questions could more rightly fall under the designer, which isn't necessarily the front end developer and would probably be better off having a lower weight (if considered at all over the technical questions) for a developer. +1 for the technical stuff, though.

Comment: @Shauna in a lot of places the front end developer is also the designer. A developer with good HTML/CSS can still make a website look good and polished. A designer makes a website look "Wow!". If you need a designer to make your website look good and polished then your front end developer is a JavaScript developer. I can't, I'm a JavaScript developer ;)

Comment: @Raynos - I think that depends on the structure of the company. For example, where I'm at now, I often get overridden on design choices, even when I think they're a terrible idea. So I effectively have no say. I'd rather not be docked because of someone else's decisions, you know? :)

Comment: @Shauna depends whether the designer is any good. If he gives me shit HTML then I won't put up with it. There's a line between different / not the way I would do it and wrong. Don't put up with wrong.

Comment: @Raynos - How would you respond when it's the owner of the company and no amount of protesting will change his mind?

Comment: @Shauna - you could always leave :)  Left my last job which was a giant blue chip corporation where front enders had no say.  Lasted 2 1/2 years until i could take it no longer.  Now with a much smaller organisation where i get to do things my way as none of them are as good @ front end as me :)

Comment: @Shauna tell him your more technically able and that you do not appreciate being forced to write bad code. Then give him that big list of reasons why your methods are better. Maybe skip one up the chain ;)

Comment: @Ryan - Idealogically, I agree with you. Unfortunately, jobs that allow me to work from home are few and far between, and it's a major factor for me right now. @Raynos - Can't skip up the chain when there's no one above. :P I've given him reasons before and he won't listen. *facepalm* And yes, I do keep my ear to the ground for new leads.

Comment: @Ryan/Raynos - Though I do have to admit, it's nice getting to say "I told you so" every so often. :)